# http://localhost:80 is not working on running Apache server through UniServer ZeroXIII

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I am unable to configure a PHP/MySQL/Apache environment on my local machine using **UniServer ZeroXIII.**

In my Uniserver ZeroXIII control panel the Apache and MySQL status is shown as started, but localhost URL is not working.

When I start Apache in the Uniserver, I get the following error message
[Failed to execute "http:\localhost:80\index.php" :87](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bu8c.png)

I have tried the following methods but still I am unable to fix this issue:

1. I tried to reinstall after uninstalling several time.
2. I tried to restart Uniserver several time
3. I changed the "Listen 80" to Listen localhost: 80, localhost: 8080, 127.0.0.1:80, 127.0.0.1:8080, but it still does not work.
4. I changed the port apache= 8080 and apache ssl port = 444.

I remember that, everything worked very well when I first tried. And when I try again it has error. I am using Windows 8.1 and Avast Free antivirus. Installed Uniserver in directory `C:\\Uniserver` location, and my program files and OS are in the same directory in `C:`.

Comment: port 80 is the default port so don't need to call it manually like localhost:80. Just use as localhost.

Comment: oh oke thanks for the information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click on the micon in the services tray near the time and date on Windows and open the menu.  It will have the option to start Apache or mySQL or both, so click start than try again to look at localhost:80 in your browser.